# Using pipe() and compose() functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading through a book that is discussing built in JavaScript functions `compose()` and `pipe()` for combining functions in functional style programming.

One of the examples seems to suggest running the following as front-end code:

```
const shuffle =
    (deck, randomizer) => {
        const doShuffle = pipe(
            addRandom(randomizer),
            sortByRandom,
            map(card => card.card)
        );
        return doShuffle(deck);
    };
```

But when I try running it in the Google Developer console I get back an error saying:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: pipe is not defined
```

I've also tried in Firefox with the same results. What version of JavaScript is needed to make use of these functions?

Am I right to think these functions can only be used with node.js or some kind of pre-compiler like Babel?

*Note: I'm running Ubuntu and have tried Chromium and Firefox.*

Comment: `pipe` and `compose` are not native JavaScript functions. It sounds to me like you were reading a functional programming doc from a library like Ramda (https://ramdajs.com/). Just include that library in your page, and your code will work.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride In fact it is, but you clearly haven't conflated the two, so I retract my comment!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pipe` and `compose` aren't native functions. You'll have to add them to your javascript document in order to utilize them. This is an ES6 pipe function that you can use in modern browsers:

```
const pipe = (...fns) => x => fns.reduce((v, f) => f(v), x)
```

Here's a compose function:

```
const compose = (...fns) => x => fns.reduceRight((v, f) => f(v), x);
```

Comment: Thank you! It was the case that he did define these somewhere else in the document, but the text was written in a way which made them seem like native functions.